# How do I style a pseudoelement based on the element's own value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass

I have a mapped array of `<input`>s that are set to type="range". I can style them with Sass to make them look like I want, but I also want the styling to change based on the input's own value.

```
<div>
    <input
        id={"ts-" + index}
        className="trinary-toggle"
        type="range"
        min="-1"
        max="1"
        step="1"
        value=this.handleValue()
        onChange={(event) => {
            let thisSwitch = document.getElementById("ts-" + index);
            //unsure of what to do here. thisSwitch is undefined
        }}
    />
</div>
```

and the scss used to style the relevant parts

```
.trinary-toggle::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: #CCCCCC;
}
```

How can I change the background style of "trinary-toggle::-webkit-slider-runnable-track" depending on the value of the input?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'd need to use javascript to modify the element's style attribute directly or to apply a class depending on the input's value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of dynamically modifying the styles, I'd recommend making multiple classes and applying the correct class(es) based on the value of the input.

Here's a quick example:

```js
const ternarySliderClasses = ["trinary-toggle-red", "trinary-toggle-yellow", "trinary-toggle-green"];

class TernarySlider extends React.Component {
  state = { value: 0 };

  render() {
    const value = this.state.value;
    const stateClass = ternarySliderClasses[+value + 1];
    return ( 
      <input
        className={classNames('trinary-toggle', stateClass)}
        value={value}
        type="range"
        min="-1"
        max="1"
        step="1"
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    );
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      value: event.target.value
    });
  };
}

ReactDOM.render(<TernarySlider /> , document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.trinary-toggle::-webkit-slider-runnable-track,
.trinary-toggle::-moz-range-track {
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.trinary-toggle-red::-webkit-slider-runnable-track,
.trinary-toggle-red::-moz-range-track {
  background: #F00;
}

.trinary-toggle-yellow::-webkit-slider-runnable-track,
.trinary-toggle-yellow::-moz-range-track {
  background: #FF0;
}

.trinary-toggle-green::-webkit-slider-runnable-track,
.trinary-toggle-green::-moz-range-track {
  background: #0F0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/classnames/2.2.5/index.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: Oh wow. That's actually a much more elegant solution than the one I was aiming for. I had to make a few alterations to make it work, but I think this is exactly what I needed. Thank you.